# Restrict post to user_id

Tags: user-access, plugin-members

I only want a post to be viewable by the administrator and one user. (So I would have a post for each user)

I am thinking of using the Members plugin and meta-data/custom fields to restrict the content. This would effectively make the post private to only those with access and any one else would not even see the post and if they get the url, they will be denied.

So would using the Members plugin be the best choice or should I try a different method? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not expert on users, simplest way as for me would be to store ID (or IDs) of user in [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and check for it if user is not admin.

Some example code (not tested):

```
if(current_user_can('administrator') || in_array(get_current_user_id(), get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'allowed_users', true))) {

    the_content();
}
else {

    echo 'Post restricted';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rarst. I implemented a solution similar to the one you provided.

Comment: Any chance you could share with us the solution you implemented, @imHavoc?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use plugin such as Role Manager? You can do that easily. =)

Comment: Can you link me to this plugin? I cannot find it in the WP Plugin Directory. Also note, I do not want to create a new Role for every user.

Comment: http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager/ You can specific users' roles in group.

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for. Each user will have their own post/multiple post. But those posts will be exclusively available to them and administrators.